# multiple elements in a single grid coloumns in kendo UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I want to add two buttons to a single coloumn in kendo UI GRid. can some one help in how to do it.

```
  Html.Kendo().Grid<Employeeentity>()
    .Name("grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {

columns.Command(command => command.Custom("Button1name").Click("showDetails")).Title("coloumn name");

columns.Command(command => command.Custom("Button2name").Click("getDetails")).Title("coloumn name");

}
```

I want both the buttons to display in a single coloumn.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just ';' separate them inside the columns.Command(command => ... ) area.

```
.Columns(columns =>
    columns.Command(command => {
        command.Custom("Button1Name").Click("showDetails");
        command.Custom("Button2Name").Click("getDetails");
    });
```

See [Telerik Forum Response](http://www.telerik.com/forums/how-to-add-multiple-command-buttons-in-the-same-column#WRFzoQYcxkafkhOZsa0AYQ)

Comment: Thanks. Its working. Do I need to add any css if I want them to display one below the other. right now they are displaying one besides other.

Comment: You can either set them to display: block, or you can set the width on the column so that it wraps.  Either of those should do it.

Comment: Thanks Robin. I tried the similar approach to merge three coloumns under single coloumn. some thing like A(B|C|D) can you share some pointers on it.

Comment: So you want to display multiple fields from the datarow object ?

Comment: A kind of. I have a three fields X,Y,Z all the three comes under a group A. So I am trying to keep the main coloumn header as A and under that want to add X,Y,Z as subcoloumns.

Comment: Look at the sample for multi-column headers.  Should do exactly what you are looking for. http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/multicolumnheaders